# How do I add new value to already existing JSON file?

Tags: json, scala

I have a JSON file as

```
{
  "titlename": "periodic",
  "atom": [
    {
      "usage": "neutron",
      "dailydata": [
        {
          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:00:00Z",
          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
          "intervalvalue": 28128,
          "intervaltime": 15
        },
        {
          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:15:00Z",
          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
          "intervalvalue": 25687,
          "intervaltime": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append

```
"matter":[
  {
   "usage":"neutron",
   "intervalvalue":345678
  },
  ...
]
```

In `intervalvalue`, I need to place the aggregate value of `intervalvalues` in `dailydata` for each usage. I am using scala and I am able to read the json file. Please help me in aggregating and appending!

Comment: should not your value be `28128  + 25687  = 53815`. And your question seems unclear to me, where do you want to append `matter`, inside dailydata usage? give the expected output itself not just part of it?

Comment: I need the JSON like 

`"titlename": "periodic",
"matter":[
  {
   "usage":"neutron",
   "intervalvalue":345678
  },
  "atom": [
    {
      "usage": "neutron",
      "dailydata": [
        {
          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:00:00Z",
          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
          "intervalvalue": 28128,
          "intervaltime": 15
        },
        {
          "utcacquisitiontime": "2017-03-27T22:15:00Z",
          "datatimezone": "+02:00",
          "intervalvalue": 25687,
          "intervaltime": 15
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with dataframe to get the needed json to be appended

for that you would have to convert the json file to dataframe which can be done as

```
val json = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to the json file")
  .map(tuple => tuple._2.replace("\n", "").trim)

val df = sqlContext.read.json(json)
```

this will give you output as

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|atom                                                                                                    |titlename|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|[[WrappedArray([+02:00,15,28128,2017-03-27T22:00:00Z], [+02:00,15,25687,2017-03-27T22:15:00Z]),neutron]]|periodic |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

you should extract usage and intervalue from the dataframe which can be done as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val tobemergedDF = df.withColumn("atom", explode(col("atom")))
    .withColumn("usage", col("atom.usage"))
    .withColumn("atom", explode(col("atom.dailydata")))
    .withColumn("intervalvalue", col("atom.intervalvalue"))
    .groupBy("usage").agg(sum("intervalvalue").as("intervalvalue"))
```

tobemergedDF is as

```
+-------+-------------+
|usage  |intervalvalue|
+-------+-------------+
|neutron|53815        |
+-------+-------------+
```

Now you can just write the dataframe as json and merge two files.

Hope the answer is helpful

Comment: my pleasure @Ninja :) thanks for acceptance and an upvote :)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! but would help me in the way of concatenating the new value to the root of the original json as well!! I am not able to merge `tobemergedDF ` to root of original json. Any help shall be highly appriciated. I am new to this environment.

Comment: Great to hear that @Ninja :)